# Can you separate distinct JSON attributes into two files using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/pki-engine#lab-setup) from Vault about creating your own certificate authority. I'd like to separate [the response](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/secrets-management/pki-engine#step-4-request-certificates) (change the output to API call using cURL to see the response) into two distinct files, one file possessing the `certificate` and `issuing_ca` attributes, the other file containing the `private_key`. The tutorial is using jq to parse JSON objects, but my unfamiliarity with jq isn't helpful here, and most searches are returning info on how to **merge** JSON using jq.

I've tried running something like

```
vault write -format=json pki_int/issue/example-dot-com \                                                            
common_name="test.example.com" \    
ttl="24h" \                 
format=pem \
jq -r '.data.certificate, .data.issuing_ca > test.cert.pem \
jq -r '.data.private_key' > test.key.pem
```

or

```
vault write -format=json pki_int/issue/example-dot-com \                                                            
common_name="test.example.com" \    
ttl="24h" \                 
format=pem \
| jq -r '.data.certificate, .data.issuing_ca > test.cert.pem \
| jq -r '.data.private_key' > test.key.pem
```

but no dice.

Comment: Please add the (dummy) JSON output before parsing to JQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could abuse `jq`'s ability to write to standard error (version 1.6 or later) separately from standard output.

```
vault write -format=json pki_int/issue/example-dot-com \                                                            
common_name="test.example.com" \    
ttl="24h" \                 
format=pem \
| jq -r '.data as $f | ($f.private_key | stderr) | ($f.certificate, $f.issuing_ca)' > test.cert.pem 2> test.key.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not an issue with `jq` invocation, but the way the output files get written. Per your usage indicated, after writing the file `test.cert.pem`, the contents over the read end of the pipe (JSON output) is no longer available to extract the `private_key` contents.

To duplicate the contents over at the write end of pipe, use `tee` along with process substitution. The following should work on bash/zsh or ksh93 and not on POSIX bourne shell sh

```bash
vault write -format=json pki_int/issue/example-dot-com \                                                            
common_name="test.example.com" \    
ttl="24h" \                 
format=pem \
| tee >( jq -r '.data.certificate, .data.issuing_ca' > test.cert.pem) \
>(jq -r '.data.private_key' > test.key.pem) \
>/dev/null
```

See this in action

```bash
jq -n '{data:{certificate: "foo", issuing_ca: "bar", private_key: "zoo"}}' \
| tee >( jq -r '.data.certificate, .data.issuing_ca' > test.cert.pem) \
>(jq -r '.data.private_key' > test.key.pem) \
>/dev/null
```

and now observe the contents of both the files.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general technique for this type of problem that is worth mentioning
because it has minimal prerequisites (just jq and awk), and because
it scales well with the number of files.  Furthermore it is quite efficient in that only one invocation each of jq and awk is needed. The idea is to setup a pipeline of the form: jq ... | awk ...

There are many variants
of the technique but in the present case, the following would suffice:

```
jq -rc '
 .data
 | "test.cert.pem",
      "\t\(.certificate)",
      "\t\(.issuing_ca)", 
   "test.key.pem",
      "\t\(.private_key)"
' | awk -F\\t 'NF == 1 {fn=$1; next} {print $2 > fn}'
```

Notice that this works even if the items of interest are strings with embedded tabs.